# Android studio copy paste R.* always pastes as com.google.android.gms.ads.R.* - how to prevent?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android studio, for the longest time, whenever I copy anything with `R.*` and then paste it, it comes out as `com.google.android.gms.ads.R.*`.

For example, copying `R.layout.l` and then pasting it will result in `com.google.android.gms.ads.R.layout.l` being pasted.

How to prevent it?

I am currently using `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1`.

Comment: Strange, what do you get when you do copy-paste using the dialogue i.e. *Select Text to copy* -> *Right Click on selected text* -> *Select Copy/Paste Special on the dialogue* -> *Copy as Plain Text* -> *Then Paste*

Comment: @Tonnie Copying as plain text or pasting as plain text will give the pasted text without the `com.google.android.gms.ads.` being prefixed.